# Dynamically adding and removing fields on django template

Tags: django, formset, formsets

A newbie, I am stuck with a problem and I feel it is more to do with me reading too much about it before trying it. And now since I am trying it is confusing me. Hoping you would be able to take out some time to assist.

Here is what I am trying to do.

I would like to dynamically add model form fields on HTML. So for ex; a user is trying to add steps to a recipe, he/she can add multiple steps and may even remove some of these steps. I want this to happen dynamically on the rendered page it self.

I would like to start with a very very simple example.

I have ready formset and model formset in django docs. Also, have gone through many SO answers. There are many instances where these fields are added without using formsets.

I have tried it my self with a few examples but I think I am mixing up everything that I have read.

Also, my js is not that strong but I used it for the examples I tried they don't seem to be working but they are less of my worries.

Here is the code I tried from one of the answers on SO:

**views.py**

```
def myview(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = MyForm(request.POST, extra=request.POST.get('extra_field_count'))
    if form.is_valid():
        print "valid!"
else:
    form = MyForm()
return render(request, "test/test.html", { 'form': form })
```

**forms.py**

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    original_field = forms.CharField()
    extra_field_count = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        extra_fields = kwargs.pop('extra', 0)

        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['extra_field_count'].initial = extra_fields

        for index in range(int(extra_fields)):
            # generate extra fields in the number specified via extra_fields
            self.fields['extra_field_{index}'.format(index=index)] = \
            forms.CharField()
```

**template**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
<script>
{% block jquery %}
    form_count = $("[name=extra_field_count");
    // get extra form count so we know what index to use for the next item.
    $("#add-another").click(function() {
        element = $('<input type="text"/>');
        element.attr('name', 'extra_field_' + form_count);
        $("#forms").append(element);
        // build element and append it to our forms container

        form_count ++;
        $("[name=extra_field_count]").val(form_count);
        // increment form count so our view knows to populate 
        // that many fields for validation
    })
{% endblock %}
</script>

{% block content %}
<form method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
<div id="forms">
    {{ form.as_p }}
</div>
<button id="add-another">add another</button>
<input type="submit" />
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

Well, this wasn't successful. When I click "Add another Field" the page reloads and gives this Value Error "invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'NaN'". Anyway I don't know if this is the right solution for me. little confused I would get this with formset for ModelForm.

Comment: Try posting the code you have so far - it's much easier to comment on specific code.

Comment: so far you seem to be on the right track to use `FormSet`. please post some code so that community can help you with your specific code concerns

Comment: I use this plugin https://github.com/elo80ka/django-dynamic-formset. Please take a look.

Comment: @ShangWang Thanks for your response. I am using Django 1.8 and django dynamic formset is not installing on it I guess it is due to compatibility issues.

Comment: @henrikstroem Thanks for your response. I am tempted to paste the code but I have tried so many variations and it does not make sense to me anymore. I will have to write the code again which I will do. It would be helpful if I get a very simple example for comprehension. I will also share my code once I complete it.

Comment: @miki725 Thanks for your response. as I have mentioned the above answer my code is a little messed up a bit. I will re-write but it would be help if a simple example for comprehension is provided. One thing I would like to add that fields should also be updated on Django model.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning a string to form_count:

```
form_count = $("[name=extra_field_count");
```

and trying to increment it.

```
form_count ++;
```

try instead:

```
form_count = parseInt($("#id_extra_field_count").val(),10);
```